# Why is VSIZE so much larger for 64 bit Linux process?

Tags: linux, memory-management

My basic question is why is the VSIZE for a 64 bit process so much larger than that of the exact same program compiled for 32 bit?

The following is the output of the /proc/<pid>/maps file for the 32 bit process.

```
00148000-00149000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0               [vdso]
00149000-002d2000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 8914142         /lib/libc-2.12.so
002d2000-002d3000 ---p 00189000 fd:02 8914142         /lib/libc-2.12.so
002d3000-002d5000 r--p 00189000 fd:02 8914142         /lib/libc-2.12.so
002d5000-002d6000 rw-p 0018b000 fd:02 8914142         /lib/libc-2.12.so
002d6000-002d9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
005c9000-005da000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 17059392        /tmp/vsizetest/lib/libtesting.so
005da000-005db000 rw-p 00010000 fd:02 17059392        /tmp/vsizetest/lib/libtesting.so
005db000-0061b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00661000-00689000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 8917713         /lib/libm-2.12.so
00689000-0068a000 r--p 00027000 fd:02 8917713         /lib/libm-2.12.so
0068a000-0068b000 rw-p 00028000 fd:02 8917713         /lib/libm-2.12.so
00694000-006ab000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 8917680         /lib/libpthread-2.12.so
006ab000-006ac000 r--p 00016000 fd:02 8917680         /lib/libpthread-2.12.so
006ac000-006ad000 rw-p 00017000 fd:02 8917680         /lib/libpthread-2.12.so
006ad000-006af000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
006e5000-00703000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 3150403         /lib/ld-2.12.so
00703000-00704000 r--p 0001d000 fd:00 3150403         /lib/ld-2.12.so
00704000-00705000 rw-p 0001e000 fd:00 3150403         /lib/ld-2.12.so
00983000-009a0000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 8914997         /lib/libgcc_s-4.4.5-20110214.so.1
009a0000-009a1000 rw-p 0001d000 fd:02 8914997         /lib/libgcc_s-4.4.5-20110214.so.1
00ca5000-00d86000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 6300601         /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
00d86000-00d8a000 r--p 000e0000 fd:02 6300601         /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
00d8a000-00d8c000 rw-p 000e4000 fd:02 6300601         /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
00d8c000-00d92000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 21134666        /tmp/vsizetest/bin/testvsz
08049000-0804a000 rw-p 00000000 fd:02 21134666        /tmp/vsizetest/bin/testvsz
09b8d000-09bae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0               [heap]
f7796000-f779c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ff998000-ff9ae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0               [stack]
```

Which results in a total VSIZE of 3656.

The following is the output of the /proc/<pid>/maps file for the 64 bit process.

```
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 21134667              /tmp/vsizetest/bin64/testvsz
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 fd:02 21134667              /tmp/vsizetest/bin64/testvsz
02301000-02322000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                     [heap]
3b7c800000-3b7c820000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 661349            /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3b7ca1f000-3b7ca20000 r--p 0001f000 fd:00 661349            /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3b7ca20000-3b7ca21000 rw-p 00020000 fd:00 661349            /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3b7ca21000-3b7ca22000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3b7cc00000-3b7cd86000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 661350            /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3b7cd86000-3b7cf86000 ---p 00186000 fd:00 661350            /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3b7cf86000-3b7cf8a000 r--p 00186000 fd:00 661350            /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3b7cf8a000-3b7cf8b000 rw-p 0018a000 fd:00 661350            /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3b7cf8b000-3b7cf90000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3b7d000000-3b7d083000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 661365            /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3b7d083000-3b7d282000 ---p 00083000 fd:00 661365            /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3b7d282000-3b7d283000 r--p 00082000 fd:00 661365            /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3b7d283000-3b7d284000 rw-p 00083000 fd:00 661365            /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3b7d800000-3b7d817000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 661352            /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3b7d817000-3b7da16000 ---p 00017000 fd:00 661352            /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3b7da16000-3b7da17000 r--p 00016000 fd:00 661352            /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3b7da17000-3b7da18000 rw-p 00017000 fd:00 661352            /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3b7da18000-3b7da1c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3b7e000000-3b7e007000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 661361            /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3b7e007000-3b7e206000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 661361            /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3b7e206000-3b7e207000 r--p 00006000 fd:00 661361            /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3b7e207000-3b7e208000 rw-p 00007000 fd:00 661361            /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3b87000000-3b87016000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 664219            /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.6-20110824.so.1
3b87016000-3b87215000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 664219            /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.6-20110824.so.1
3b87215000-3b87216000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 664219            /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.6-20110824.so.1
3d44c00000-3d44ce8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 3019214           /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
3d44ce8000-3d44ee8000 ---p 000e8000 fd:00 3019214           /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
3d44ee8000-3d44eef000 r--p 000e8000 fd:00 3019214           /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
3d44eef000-3d44ef1000 rw-p 000ef000 fd:00 3019214           /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
3d44ef1000-3d44f06000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f30ab397000-7f30ab39c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f30ab39c000-7f30ab3ad000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 21127804      /tmp/vsizetest/lib64/libtesting.so
7f30ab3ad000-7f30ab5ac000 ---p 00011000 fd:02 21127804      /tmp/vsizetest/lib64/libtesting.so
7f30ab5ac000-7f30ab5ad000 rw-p 00010000 fd:02 21127804      /tmp/vsizetest/lib64/libtesting.so
7f30ab5ad000-7f30ab5ee000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f30ab606000-7f30ab609000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff69512000-7fff69528000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0             [stack]
7fff695ff000-7fff69600000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0             [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0     [vsyscall]
```

Which results in a VSIZE of 18480.

The major difference between the 2 maps are the following entries from the 64 bit data:

```
3b7cd86000-3b7cf86000 ---p 00186000 fd:00 661350             /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3b7d083000-3b7d282000 ---p 00083000 fd:00 661365             /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3b7d817000-3b7da16000 ---p 00017000 fd:00 661352             /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3b7e007000-3b7e206000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 661361             /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3b87016000-3b87215000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 664219             /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.6-20110824.so.1
3d44ce8000-3d44ee8000 ---p 000e8000 fd:00 3019214            /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
7f30ab3ad000-7f30ab5ac000 ---p 00011000 fd:02 21127804       /tmp/vsizetest/lib64/libtesting.so
```

Which account for 14316 of the 18480 VSIZE.

Other experimentation with other programs seems to show that in 64 bit you seem to get one of these private, non-readable, non-writeable, non-executable chunks of memory for each shared library that is used by the process, while in 32 bit there are hardly any of these chunks.

Does anyone know what these chunks of memory are?

Note: Based on some answers to a similar question, [What these memory regions for, from a Linux process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568043/what-these-memory-regions-for-from-a-linux-process), this is not a multi-threaded process and it is already compiled -fPIC.

Answer (score 8):

The major VSIZE difference comes from how the PROT_NONE mappings (mode "---p") of the shared libraries are done in the case of the 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

These are exactly the mappings that you spotted as producing the difference.

In general for each shared library loaded we will have four mappings:

```
3b7cc00000-3b7cd86000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 661350            /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3b7cd86000-3b7cf86000 ---p 00186000 fd:00 661350            /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3b7cf86000-3b7cf8a000 r--p 00186000 fd:00 661350            /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3b7cf8a000-3b7cf8b000 rw-p 0018a000 fd:00 661350            /lib64/libc-2.12.so
```

The first one is the code segment with executable permissions, the second the PROT_NONE (mode ---) mapping (pages may not be accessed), and the last two ones the data segment (read only part and read write).

The PROT_NONE has size MAXPAGESIZE and so it is created differently in the 32-bit and 64-bit versions. In the case of the 32-bit version it has 4KB size (MAXPAGESIZE for i386) and in the case of the 64-bit version 2MB (standard MAXPAGESIZE for x86_64 systems).

It should be noted that this memory is not actually consumed (it just consumes addresses of the address space) as noted here:

http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/dataseg.html

"This extra doesn’t cost you any RAM or swap space, just address space within each process, which is in plentiful supply on 64-bit platforms. The underlying reason is to do with keeping libraries efficiently sharable, but the implementation is a little odd."

Just a last trick, I find easier to check memory mappings using the pmap utility than parses the maps file and produces a simpler to read output:

For basic info:

```
pmap <PID>
```

For extended info:

```
pmap -x <PID>
```

Comment: nice answer, pointed memory is loaded by page.  Just add that pmap is implemented by reading "/proc/<pid>/maps"... :-)

Comment: Just modified the sentence to make clear how pmap works. The best point about pmap is that it parses the maps file and calculates the size of the regions for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Not really an answer... speaking past my knowledge]

If the memory segments are really "private, non-readable, non-writeable, non-executable" then they should never be referred to, and even though they exist in the VIRTUAL memory space, they will never occupy any real memory, and therefore not much to worry about. (?)

It must be some sort of book-keeping or fragmentation issue.  Since these are part of the shared libraries (*.so) it's just how those libraries were built.  It really has nothing to do with your program, other than it's linked to those libraries.  Unless you want to rebuild those libraries, or not use them, there isn't much to do about it (and not much to gain anyway as they should use no real memory anyway).

Maybe related?
In [What these memory regions for, from a Linux process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568043/what-these-memory-regions-for-from-a-linux-process?rq=1)

@caf says some memory segments that are "---p" are "guard pages".

That suggests they exist just to catch a stray pointer or stack growing to far error... sort of a hard separator in memory so the system can catch a common error and stop processing rather than let those common errors slip by (its a fatal error to refer to them at all, and they really will NEVER use any real memory).

Answer (score 1):

Answering to why and what constitutes a 64bit shared library has a additional chunk of memory, is by taking example of loading `libc.so` and looking this from how loader loads dynamic libraries. Below are `strace` outputs for both 32bit and 64bit executables which tells us there are calls to `mmap` & `mprotect`.

```
esunboj@L9AGC12:~/32_64bit$ strace ./crash-x86-64
...
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\30\2\0\0\0\0\0"...,
832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1811128, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3925208, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) =    
0x7fa354f8a000
mprotect(0x7fa35513f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fa35533e000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE,
3, 0x1b4000) = 0x7fa35533e000
mmap(0x7fa355344000, 17624, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS,
-1, 0) = 0x7fa355344000
close(3)                                = 0
...
```

> ```
> esunboj@L9AGC12:~/32_64bit$ strace ./crash
> ...
> open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
> read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0000\226\1\0004\0\0\0"...,
> 512) = 512
> fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1730024, ...}) = 0
> mmap2(NULL, 1743580, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 
> 0xfffffffff7546000
> mprotect(0xf76e9000, 4096, PROT_NONE)   = 0
> mmap2(0xf76ea000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE,  
> 3, 0x1a3) = 0xfffffffff76ea000
> mmap2(0xf76ed000, 10972, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 
> -1, 0) = 0xfffffffff76ed000
> close(3)                                = 0
> ...
> ```

Closely observing both the strace's two things are need to be investigate,

**1. Each of them maps memory 3 times and 1 call to `mprotect` exactly after first `mmap`.**

**2. Comparing `mprotect` calls for 64bit & 32bit has  `2093056B` & `4096B` of region protected respectively.**

In [dl-load.c](https://github.com/ahmadia/collfs/blob/master/glibc-2.4-bgp-patches/elf/dl-load.c), subroutine [_dl_map_object_from_fd](https://github.com/ahmadia/collfs/blob/master/glibc-2.4-bgp-patches/elf/dl-load.c#L878)() maps dynamic library memory segments to virtual space by setting required permissions and zero fills `.bss` section of library and updates the link map structure. Lets get here some part of code for more analysis,

```
struct link_map *
 _dl_map_object_from_fd ( )
{
 ...
  /* Scan the program header table, collecting its load commands. */
  struct loadcmd
   {
     ElfW(Addr) mapstart, mapend, dataend, allocend;
     off_t mapoff;
     int prot;
   } loadcmds[l->l_phnum], *c; // l is link_map struct described for each object 
                                  of dynamic linker 
  size_t nloadcmds = 0;
  bool has_holes = false;
  ...
  for (ph = phdr; ph < &phdr[l->l_phnum]; ++ph)
  switch (ph->p_type)
  {
  ...
  case PT_LOAD:
  ...
    c = &loadcmds[nloadcmds++];
    c->mapstart = ph->p_vaddr & ~(GLRO(dl_pagesize) - 1);
    c->mapend = ((ph->p_vaddr + ph->p_filesz + GLRO(dl_pagesize) - 1)
                     & ~(GLRO(dl_pagesize) - 1));
  ...
    if (nloadcmds > 1 && c[-1].mapend != c->mapstart)
        has_holes = true;
  ...
  }
  ...
    if (has_holes)
       __mprotect ((caddr_t) (l->l_addr + c->mapend),
          loadcmds[nloadcmds - 1].mapstart - c->mapend, PROT_NONE);
  ...
}
```

In the above code `l_phnum` used in `for` statement holds number of entries in the ELF program header. Ideally for each iteration each entry segments are mapped. When `PT_LOAD` segment case hits for its first time, its basically a `.text` or `.rodata` section which gets mmapped (1st `mmap` in strace) and second `PT_LOAD` segment represents `.data`section gets mapped (2nd `mmap` in strace). Before second `PT_LOAD` segment is mapped, `mapstart` and `mapend` is preserved which refer to start and end of text section. In next `PT_LOAD` iteration if previous segment `mapend` not equals to current (.data) segment `mapstart` then their is a hole between two `PT_LOAD` segments (meaning gap between `.text` and `.data` sections). Therefore, if their is a hole between memory regions with null permissions, loader will protect (`mprotect` call in strace) it or make it inaccessible. Protected region for 64bit and 32 bit process are **511** Vs just **1** page respectively adding to huge memory chunk for 64bit libraries.

**Proof for 64bit inaccessible region**: Objdump for `libc.so` below gives us some virtual address(VA) statistics which are roundoff appropriately as follows,

```
                 PT_LOAD(1)              PT_LOAD(2)                    
mapstart VA   0x0000000000000000     0x00000000003b4000   
mapend   VA   0x00000000001b5000     0x00000000003A0000
```

Here `PT_LOAD(1) mapend` (0x00000000001b5000) is not equal to `PT_LOAD(2) mapstart` (0x00000000003b4000) resulting a memory hole of 0x00000000001FF000 (In decimal `2093056B`).

> ```
> esunboj@L9AGC12:~/32_64bit$objdump -x -s -d -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 
> Program Header: 
> ...
>   LOAD off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000000000 paddr 0x0000000000000000 align 2**21
>        filesz 0x00000000001b411c memsz 0x00000000001b411c flags r-x
>   LOAD off    0x00000000001b4700 vaddr 0x00000000003b4700 paddr 0x00000000003b4700 align 2**21
>        filesz 0x0000000000005160 memsz 0x0000000000009dd8 flags rw- 
> ...
> ```

On top 64bit text takes a higher representation of instruction bytes compared to 32bit. Similarly size of pointers on 64bit are `8B` adding `4` more bytes. Also data structure alignment is a `8B` aligned in 64bit making mapped regions larger.

Simple `size` command on binaries can show the difference between 32/64 bit programs memory regions as below,

```
esunboj@L9AGC12:~/32_64bit$ ls -lrt
total 10368
-rwxrwxrwx 1 esunboj ei 5758776 Oct 10 11:35 crash-x86-64
-rwxrwxrwx 1 esunboj ei 4855676 Oct 10 11:36 crash
esunboj@L9AGC12:~/32_64bit$ size crash
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
4771286   82468  308704 5162458  4ec5da crash
esunboj@L9AGC12:~/32_64bit$ size crash-x86-64 
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
5634861  121164 1623728 7379753  709b29 crash-x86-64
```